# Repeated measures ANOVA in R (split-plot design)

Tags: r, lm, anova

I am trying to fit a repeated measures ANOVA from an experiment with a split-split-plot design and several measures over time.

The experimental design is as follows:

I have **9 blocks** in the field. Inside each block I have two subplots representing a split factor (named **trt**, "with" or "without" a specific treatment). Inside each subplot (with or without) I have another split factor with two quadrats (named **sp**, "species 1", "Species 2"). In each quadrat I have two seedlings of each species in the study (each seedling identified by a unique id). Finally I have monitored a given response variable for each seedling in the experiment along 4 repeated measures in time (weeks).

Therefore, I have 9 blocks, 2 treatments inside each block, 2 species inside each treatment and 2 seedlings from each species. This was monitored for 4 weeks.

I want to understand if time * trt * sp affect my response variable.

Considering my experimental design, is the following code a correct specification of the Error term for fitting an aov repeated measures split-split-plot model?

```r
fit <- aov(response ~ time * sp * trt + Error(block/trt/sp/id), data = d3)
summary(fit)

Error: block
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals  1  11.29   11.29               

Error: block:trt
    Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
trt  1  0.114   0.114

Error: block:trt:sp
       Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
sp      1  61.14   61.14
sp:trt  1  10.27   10.27

Error: block:trt:sp:id
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
sp         1   7.16   7.159   2.299  0.141
trt        1   1.07   1.072   0.344  0.562
sp:trt     1   2.18   2.181   0.701  0.410
Residuals 28  87.17   3.113               

Error: Within
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
time          1   0.38  0.3781   0.237  0.627
time:sp       1   0.93  0.9317   0.585  0.446
time:trt      1   1.91  1.9117   1.201  0.276
time:sp:trt   1   2.73  2.7257   1.712  0.194
Residuals   104 165.59  1.5922
```

This code results in the following Warning message:

```r
Warning message:
In aov(response ~ time * sp * trt + Error(block/trt/sp/id), data = d3) :
  Error() model is singular
```

I really appreciate any help on this issue. 
Thank you very much! I am happy to provide any further detail, if need it.

### Data and plots

To illustrate the results
[image]

Data for reproducibility is presented below (dput print):

Edit 1 (updated datset):

```
structure(list(block = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), trt = c("without", "without", "with", 
"with", "with", "with", "without", "without", "with", "with", 
"without", "without", "with", "with", "without", "without", "with", 
"with", "without", "without", "with", "with", "without", "without", 
"without", "without", "with", "with", "with", "with", "without", 
"without", "without", "without", "with", "with", "without", "without", 
"with", "with", "with", "with", "without", "without", "with", 
"with", "without", "without", "with", "with", "without", "without", 
"with", "with", "without", "without", "with", "with", "without", 
"without", "without", "without", "with", "with", "with", "with", 
"without", "without", "without", "without", "with", "with", "without", 
"without", "with", "with", "with", "with", "without", "without", 
"with", "with", "without", "without", "with", "with", "without", 
"without", "with", "with", "without", "without", "with", "with", 
"without", "without", "without", "without", "with", "with", "with", 
"with", "without", "without", "without", "without", "with", "with", 
"without", "without", "with", "with", "with", "with", "without", 
"without", "with", "with", "without", "without", "with", "with", 
"without", "without", "with", "with", "without", "without", "with", 
"with", "without", "without", "without", "without", "with", "with", 
"with", "with", "without", "without", "without", "without", "with", 
"with"), sp = c("species 1", "species 2", "species 2", "species 1", 
"species 2", "species 1", "species 2", "species 1", "species 1", 
"species 2", "species 2", "species 1", "species 2", "species 1", 
"species 1", "species 2", "species 1", "species 2", "species 2", 
"species 1", "species 2", "species 1", "species 1", "species 2", 
"species 1", "species 2", "species 1", "species 2", "species 1", 
"species 2", "species 2", "species 1", "species 2", "species 1", 
"species 2", "species 1", "species 1", "species 2", "species 2", 
"species 1", "species 2", "species 1", "species 2", "species 1", 
"species 1", "species 2", "species 2", "species 1", "species 2", 
"species 1", "species 1", "species 2", "species 1", "species 2", 
"species 2", "species 1", "species 2", "species 1", "species 1", 
"species 2", "species 1", "species 2", "species 1", "species 2", 
"species 1", "species 2", "species 2", "species 1", "species 2", 
"species 1", "species 2", "species 1", "species 1", "species 2", 
"species 2", "species 1", "species 2", "species 1", "species 2", 
"species 1", "species 1", "species 2", "species 2", "species 1", 
"species 2", "species 1", "species 1", "species 2", "species 1", 
"species 2", "species 2", "species 1", "species 2", "species 1", 
"species 1", "species 2", "species 1", "species 2", "species 1", 
"species 2", "species 1", "species 2", "species 2", "species 1", 
"species 2", "species 1", "species 2", "species 1", "species 1", 
"species 2", "species 2", "species 1", "species 2", "species 1", 
"species 2", "species 1", "species 1", "species 2", "species 2", 
"species 1", "species 2", "species 1", "species 1", "species 2", 
"species 1", "species 2", "species 2", "species 1", "species 2", 
"species 1", "species 1", "species 2", "species 1", "species 2", 
"species 1", "species 2", "species 1", "species 2", "species 2", 
"species 1", "species 2", "species 1", "species 2", "species 1"
), id = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
36L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
"10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", 
"21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", 
"32", "33", "34", "35", "36"), class = "factor"), time = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
    response = c(3.1, 5.7, 4.8, 2.9, 5, 3.9, 5.7, 4.2, 3.6, 4.4, 
    3.9, 2.9, 3.2, 7.5, 4.3, 4.8, 3, 4.9, 5.6, 3.9, 4.1, 4.2, 
    2.8, 3.9, 3.9, 7.5, 4, 4.3, 3.1, 7.1, 5.8, 2.5, 6.4, 4.5, 
    5, 3.6, 3.1, 5.2, 3.6, 2.9, 5.2, 4.6, 4.7, 4.3, 3.9, 4.4, 
    4.2, 3.6, 3.2, 2.7, 3.4, 5.6, 2.8, 6, 5.1, 3.7, 4.1, 3.4, 
    3, 4.1, 3.2, 6.7, 3.1, 3.8, 2.9, 6.9, 5.6, 2.1, 5.6, 4.8, 
    4.8, 2.7, 3, 5.5, 3.4, 3.1, 5.1, 5, 5, 4.8, 4, 4, 4, 2.6, 
    3, 3, 3.9, 6, 3, 7, 5, 3.5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 6.5, 4, 5, 4, 
    8, 6, 2.2, 5.9, 4, 6, 3, 3, 5, 3.5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 2, 6.5, 4, 
    5, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5.5, 2, 5, 6, 2.5, 5, 2.5, 3, 5, 3, 5.5, 3, 
    2, 3, 6, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 15)), row.names = c(NA, -144L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Why do you need all those terms in your error? Don't you only need to account for `block`?

Comment: Hi @Axeman, thanks. The way I see it, I have factors structured in space (split-split-plot design). Inside my block I have a slit where half of the plot received on treatment while the other have another treatment and so on. Thus I must account for this structure because it is not a fully randomized design. If I include only the block in the error I will miss the block/trt/sp spatial structure of the experiment. Right?

Comment: Ok, I can see that for treatment nested within block, but not sure about species. Also, your example data.frame doesn't have `id`. You don't really have enough samples to fit these four random effects.

Comment: Yep I agree. The number of samples are not enough. But this is a crop of the data. I have updated the dataset to include the id variable. Regarding the species, It is a second split-factor in the experiment, so as I understand it should be included in the Error term. But I am not sure about the id term. If I remove id from the Error, e.g  ```aov(response ~ time * sp * trt + Error(block/trt/sp), data = d3)```, the Warning message is gone.

Comment: Something's gotta give. I'd be inclined to fit a model with crossed random effects, e.g. `lme4::lmer(response ~ time * sp * trt + (1 | block) + (time | id), d3)`.

Comment: Pardon the interruption but this question is out of scope on StackOverflow. We help troubleshoot non-working code not provide insight to modeling specifications. Consider https://stats.stackexchange.com/ or https://datascience.stackexchange.com/. Voting to migrate this question.

Comment: I agree, and have voted to move. (Also, I recommend plotting with `ggplot(df, aes(time, response, color = trt, group = interaction(trt, id))) + geom_point() + geom_line() + facet_wrap(block~.)` to see the different factors at play here.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Parfait, you are right,  should move this question to cross Validated!